# Looking for feedbacks to implement continuous deployment on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I would like to implement continuous deployment on my Kubernetes-based infrastructure and I'm looking for advice. I already use a CI tool. All the manifests are currently stored on git, the same way one would store it to use GitOps.

From my research, I see 3 ways to implement continuous deployment:

- write and maintain homemade scripts (basically run `kubectl apply -f` or `helm install`)
- use a comprehensive CI/CD tool (like GitLab)
- use a dedicated CD tool (like Spinnaker, ArgoCD, ...)

Could you explain me which option you chose and why? And are you satisfied with it or do you think you will change in the future?

Thank you very much for your answers

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference in your options. CICD services are triggered from your git-repository-service with a *hook*. Your CICD pipeline e.g. [GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/) or [ArgoCD](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/) will then apply your config with e.g. `kubectl apply -k somepath/` using [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) for environment parameters (or alternatively with [Helm](https://helm.sh/)).

Comment: Hi Jonas, thank you for your answer. Well actually I know some people do not use CD tools such as ArgoCD and better write their very own simple commands to deploy their stuff, as part of their CI pipeline. I would like to know what are the benefits of doing so, in terms of deployment + maintenance + costs overhead versus capabilities. Does it make sense to you ?

Comment: @vesna everyone has different requirements and needs when it comes to CICD, but most likely you want it triggered with a hook on commit to a git repository.